# Swift : button function not executing

Tags: ios, swift3

so i have this function code for the button

```
@objc func facebookButtonPressed(_ urlString : String)
    {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!;
        let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url);
        self.present(safariViewController, animated: true,completion: nil);
    }
```

and im attaching this function to my button as such

```
cell.facebookButton.addTarget(cell.facebookButton, action: #selector(facebookButtonPressed(_:facebookHandles[0])), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside);
```

the facebookHandles looks as such :

```
let facebookHandles = ["https://www.facebook.com/harsh.mutha.902","https://www.facebook.com/skvrahul?fb_dtsg_ag=AdzxdqYcNvlFjd6QcX6a2sTXKagTQsR_OCuyHLe8z8gPug%3AAdxQz3YDUQ3tL-a7ME_0Owzu-02FSL0SO7VWqcJ_CpPUrw","https://www.facebook.com/saptarshi.roychaudhuri?fb_dtsg_ag=AdzxdqYcNvlFjd6QcX6a2sTXKagTQsR_OCuyHLe8z8gPug%3AAdxQz3YDUQ3tL-a7ME_0Owzu-02FSL0SO7VWqcJ_CpPUrw"];
```

why am i getting this error and how do i fix it ?

```
Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer
```

[collection view where the buttons are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlBML.png)

as you can see from the image there are multiple buttons in the collection view for each cell . 
now how do i appropriately open the facebook page for the developer when the facebook button of that developer cell is clicked??

Comment: You cannot pass custom parameters through the action, that's impossible. Either pass no parameter or the affected UI element and the event, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You cant' change parameter of type `UIButton` to `String` , You may need  inside `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.facebookButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(facebookButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
cell.facebookButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

And inside the vc implement

```
@objc func facebookButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
  print(facebookHandles[sender.tag])
  let url = URL(string: facebookHandles[sender.tag])!
  let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
  self.present(safariViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: but this button is part of a collection view cell so there will be multiple similar buttons . now how do i open the correct facebook page according the facebook button of the cell when its clicked ??

Comment: you set that target inside cellForItemAt ??

Comment: are you asking me or telling me?